# Problem with authorized_keys with ansible

Tags: ansible, rights, authorized-keys

I am in the process of making knots in my brain concerning a concern for rights on the `.ssh/authorized_keys`.

I have my ansible script that works perfectly for creating my users on my servers and I just want to modify the rights of `/home/user`, `/home/user/.ssh` and finally `/home/user.ssh/authorized_keys` because they are not correct by default.
I can't find where the problem is.

```yml
---
- hosts: all
  become: true
  tasks:
  - name: Creation groupe dev
    group:
      name: dev
      state: present

  - name: Creation des utilisateurs
    user:
      name: "{{ item.path }}"
      group: dev
      state: present
      password: "{{ lookup('password', '/dev/null') |password_hash('sha512') }}"
      update_password: on_create
    with_filetree: xx_pub_keys/

  - name: copie des clés SSH
    authorized_key:
      user: "{{ item.path }}"
      key: "{{ lookup('file', 'xx_pub_keys/' + item.path ) }}"
      state: present
    with_filetree: xx_pub_keys/

  - name: droits repertoires
    command:
      chmod go-w /home/{{ user.path }} && \
      chmod 700 /home/{{ user.path }} && \
      chmod 644 /home/{{ user.path }}/.ssh/authorized_keys

  - name: "Suppression des users eventuels"
    user:
      name: "{{ item.path }}"
      state: absent
      remove: true
    with_filetree: xx_pub_remove/

  - name: Allow admin users to sudo without a password
    lineinfile:
      dest: "/etc/sudoers"
      state: "present"
      regexp: "^%admin"
      line: "%admin ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL"

  - name: restart sshd
    service: name=ssh state=restarted ...
```

So I tried in the "directory rights" section `user.path`, `item.path`, short item with `with_items` ...
I have no idea ...

In short, I am in favor of any correction.

thank you in advance

Comment: What do you mean by “not correct by default ?” What would you expect and what do you actually get ?

Comment: Can you edit the post so that Ansible playbook is more readable? Post it "as a code"

Comment: authorized_keys are not 0644 .                                           

`root@zen:/home# ls -la
total 56
drwxr-xr-x  3 user1  dev   4096 avril 10 14:41 user1  => manually changed
drwxrwxr-x  2 user2  dev   4096 avril  9 14:01 user2 => ansible install

root@zen:/home# ls -la user2/
drwx------  2 user2 dev  4096 avril 10 15:18 .ssh
root@zen:/home# ls -la s.user2/.ssh/
-rw------- 1 user2 dev  400 avril 10 15:18 authorized_keys  
And for user1 :
-rw-r--r-- 1 user1 dev  222 avril 10 14:41 authorized_keys`

Comment: sorry for code format ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i look on the task

```
  - name: droits repertoires
    command:
      chmod go-w /home/{{ user.path }} && \
      chmod 700 /home/{{ user.path }} && \
      chmod 644 /home/{{ user.path }}/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

it makes no sense to remove write-right from group other if you set the rights absolut later on to 700. In other words the first command is superfluous.

and then prefere always a module instead of a command if a module exist for that kind of task. So here you use the file module 2 times instead of command module:

```
  - name: "check or change /home/{{ user.path }}"
    file:
      path: /home/{{ user.path }}
      state: touch
      mode: '700'
  - name: "check or change /home/{{ user.path }}/.ssh/authorized_keys"
    file:
      path: /home/{{ user.path }}/.ssh/authorized_keys
      state: touch
      mode: '644'
```

Comment: and please paste your error message, so it is easier to help

Comment: No error. It didn't apply rights. But your answer Oliver works. Thank you !